# How to fetch all conversations in one subject gmail

Tags: go, gmail, imap

I using `emersion/go-imap` to get data in gmail have one problem. I can't take all message (reply in subject) like this

[image]

I can get only last message of sender message. Have any solution to get all reply message?

My code pattern have round to feed mail data about 5 min/round and this problem if sender send reply in one subject more that 1 reply. I can't get first message. I can get only last message of sender

that some code:

```
// List mailboxes ลิสต์ mailbox ของแต่ละ channel
mailboxes := make(chan *imap.MailboxInfo, 10)
done := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
    done <- c.List("", "*", mailboxes)
}()

log.Println("Mailboxes:")
for m := range mailboxes {
    log.Println("* " + m.Name)
}

if err := <-done; err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

listBox := "INBOX"

// Select INBOX
mbox, err := c.Select(listBox, false)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// set range for feed
seqSet := new(imap.SeqSet)
// is for testing get lastone only
seqSet.AddRange(mbox.Messages, mbox.Messages)

log.Println("message lens : ", (mbox.Messages))

// Get the whole message body
var section imap.BodySectionName

items := []imap.FetchItem{section.FetchItem(), imap.FetchEnvelope}

// criteria := imap.NewSearchCriteria()

messages := make(chan *imap.Message, 10)
go func() {
    if err := c.Fetch(seqSet, items, messages); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}()

msg := <-messages
if msg == nil {
    log.Fatal("Server didn't returned message")
}

// Create a new mail reader
mailReader, err := mail.CreateReader(msg.GetBody(&section))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Print some info about the message
header := mailReader.Header
if ID, err := header.MessageID(); err == nil {
    log.Println("ID:", ID)
}

if date, err := header.Date(); err == nil {
    log.Println("Date:", date)
}
if from, err := header.AddressList("From"); err == nil {
    log.Println("From:", from)
}
if to, err := header.AddressList("To"); err == nil {
    log.Println("To:", to)
}
if subject, err := header.Subject(); err == nil {
    log.Println("Subject:", subject)
}

// Process each message's part
count := 0
for {
    p, err := mailReader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    switch h := p.Header.(type) {
    case *mail.InlineHeader:
        // This is the message's text (can be plain-text or HTML)
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(p.Body)
        fmt.Printf("Got text: %v\n", string(b))
    case *mail.AttachmentHeader:
        // This is an attachment
        filename, _ := h.Filename()
        fmt.Printf("Got attachment: %v\n", filename)
        // set filename
        file, err := os.Create(filename)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        // create file
        // using io.Copy instead of io.ReadAll to avoid insufficient memory issues
        size, err := io.Copy(file, p.Body)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Saved %v bytes into %v\n", size, filename)

    }
    count++
}
fmt.Printf("\n\nRound of mail : %v", count)
```

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry for provides little information. I edit my post for more information. And you want more information. Let me know.

Comment: If you want to use plain IMAP then I would try to see what your library of choice provides for finding messages based on the `In-Reply-To` and `References` fields in the header of a particular e-mail message. See [this](https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html) for more background info. Note that if your solution won't require working with mail hosters other than gmail, you can look what gmail web APIs may offer you: maybe there is existing functionality for chasing what gmail considers message threads—it may have different idea than the "classic" [MUAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client).

Comment: @kostix Thank you for advice. I find a new way to get all conversation gmail is have setting about grouping mail reply. If is off mail of reply is can feed all of conversations (That show like one mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to feed all of conversations in gmail. Gmail is have setting about grouping mail. I turn off this setting mail of reply will show one by one mail and can get data what I want.

going to settings --> turn of conversation view.

[image: setting picture]